# Warranty nukeproof mega elite 290 carbon M

Tags: mountain-bike, frames

Does anyone have any info on what the warranty would be for all parts on my carbon nukeproof mega have (bought from chain reaction cycles)? Thanks!

Comment: Judging from its name, I presume the warranty covers for example nuclear explosions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nukeproof warranty covers the original purchaser from defects in materials, paint and workmanship from the original purchase date for a period as listed below (for the nukeproof mega in question):

Nukeproof Frames = 5 Years (2016-CURRENT, excluding Downhill products)

Nukeproof Components = 2 Years

Carbon handlebars = lifetime

Nukeproof Ti Bearing HZN Headset = 5 years

Nukeproof Ti Bearing HZN Bottom Bracket = 2 years

For another nukeproof bike / product link to info is here:
https://nukeproof.com/pages/warranty

If you bought the bike before 2016, frame warranty is:

Nukeproof Frames = 2 Years (<2016)

If I've got any of this info wrong please let me know in the comments!

Comment: If you knew the answer why did you post the question ?

Comment: I didn't, someone else answered linking where i can find the info and then deleted their answer